# R loop with two break command

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to determine the first decimal place value different from zero. For example, in `0.0000082109314` it would be the sixth (or million-th), where there is an `8`.

I thought about a loop, but it's not working. So I'd rather ask in *pseudo*-code:

```
d = runif(100, min = 1e-10, max = 1e-5) # Toy data with 100 elements in a vector
position = rep(0, 100)                  # Starting an empty vector to place results
for(j in 1:100){                        # Looping through d
  for(i in 1:10){                       # Exponents from 1 to 10
    if(d[j]]) * 10^i >= 1)              # First power of 10 turning the value >  or = 1
    position[j] = i                     # Assign i to the position
    stop the looping through i and move on to the next j
  }
}
```

So I need the loop to stop replacing the `i` value as soon as the condition is fulfilled. Otherwise, any higher value of `i` will also meet the condition, and it won't return the desired first position different from zero.

I know about `break` and `next`, but how could I use them (or other commands) here?

---

The issue is to at some point within the loop (when the condition is met) to ask R to 1. Save the index, and 2. Move on to the next `j`.

```
    position = rep(0, 100)
    for(j in 1:100){
      for(i in 1:10){
    if(d[j]]) * 10^i >= 0) position[j] = i AND next
    else
    CONTINUE with i
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `ceiling(abs(log10(d)))`? As far as loop stuff, all the commands are included in the docs. Type `?\`for\``

Comment: @Frank This is elegant and beautifully short... I was hoping to learn something about the syntax of `break` and `next`...

Comment: Ah ok, thought you didn't know of those commands.

Comment: @Frank I hadn't thought of your single, elegant line, and it's great. Clunky as the loop is, though, I'd like to know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` will kick you out of your current loop.  It won't go all the way to the top level so if you use it inside of the loop indexed by i it will basically just kick you to the next value for j and restart i at 1.

Just as a note if you're going to have multiple conditions inside of your `if` statement make sure to wrap all of them in curly braces.

```
for(j in 1:3){
  for(i in 1L:6L){

    # The result of this if statement is that we skip this iteration
    # when i==2.
    if(i == 2){
      next
    }

    # The result of this if statement is that we kick out of the
    # for loop indexed by i.  The result being that we reach the end
    # of the code block for the for loop indexed by j so if we aren't
    # finished iterating over all of the values for j we go to the next
    # value for j and start the for loop with i all over again.
    if(i == 5){
      break
    }

    # Just print out what i and j are equal to. We do this after the
    # if statements so any iteration that isn't stopped by the if
    # statements will end up printing a result.
    print(sprintf("i: %i j: %i", i, j))
  }
}
```

gives the output

```
[1] "i: 1 j: 1"
[1] "i: 3 j: 1"
[1] "i: 4 j: 1"
[1] "i: 1 j: 2"
[1] "i: 3 j: 2"
[1] "i: 4 j: 2"
[1] "i: 1 j: 3"
[1] "i: 3 j: 3"
[1] "i: 4 j: 3"
```

so by using next I skip every iteration where i==2 and by using break I stop anything for i>=5 and move on to the next value for j

If you were having troubles getting break to work with your code you'd need to post what you actually tried.  There were issues other than 'break' in your code (you use d[j]] notice the mismatched square braces and I think you messed up your parenthesis on your if statement).  This is what I think you wanted:

```
d = runif(100, min = 1e-10, max = 1e-5) # Toy data with 100 elements in a vector
position = rep(0, 100)                  # Starting an empty vector to place results
for(j in 1:100){                        # Looping through d
  for(i in 1:10){                       # Exponents from 1 to 10
    if((d[j] * 10^i) >= 1){             # First power of 10 turning the value >  or = 1
        position[j] = i                     # Assign i to the position
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Toni - break does what you're asking for in your pseudocode. If you're having an issue getting it to work then I suggest posting what you actually have tried.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that avoids loops would be:

1. convert numbers to scientfic format and into a character string
2. split the string
3. extract the exponential coefficient

For your example it looks like this (`var1` = your input data, `place` is the resulting decimal place):

```
var1<-0.0000082109314
var1<-as.character(format(var1, scientific = T))
place<-strsplit(var1,"e")
place<-abs(as.numeric(place[[1]][2]))
```

(It is assumed that you have values << 1. Input data for large values must be interpreted differently, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use loops, I think this sort of problem is an excellent candidate for a `while` loop because you don't know in advance how many iterations you will need. (They are also much more likely to start running forever due to a small typo, requiring you to restart your R session.)

```
x = 0.0000082109314

zero_first = TRUE
exponent = -1
while(zero_first) {
    exponent = exponent + 1
    if(x * 10^exponent >= 1) zero_first = FALSE
}
exponent
# [1] 6
```

This could replace your inner `for` loop. Of course, it's risky so it's probably best to do some input checking.